# How to Solve a linear matrix equation of an array M = B*M*C where B and C are known

Tags: matlab, math, matrix

**Adding to the question's description :**

I **am doing Feature extraction from videos and i am trying to implement this one line of mathematical equation to matlab or even any algorithm .**

*let's say I have B and C which are 10 x 10 matrices*

*R is also a 10 x 10 matrix but it should satisfy two conditions*

*1) M == BxMxC*

*2) The Values in M should be within a given range [x( which is min) y(max)] given by the user*

i can handle the constraints of the range but i have no idea on how to proceed with the 1st condition at all , much less converting it into matlab

**I have found several solutions to this type of problem**

*1)Sylvester's equation which approximates AX+XB = C or A*X + X*B + C = 0*

*2)Lyapunov Matrix equation which approximates A*X+X*A'+Q = 0*

both of these implementations of matlab i have found in this link given below

**https://github.com/ajt60gaibb/freeLYAP**

but i need help in the mathematics area as to how i can use those (if i can) to  **M = B*M*C**

if anyone can help me get through this ... i'll be really glad

peace out

Comment: I believe this question belongs here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you multiply the whole equation by the inverse of B and put everything on the same side of the equal it becomes a Sylvester's equation with last matrix null. Did you try to run something like lyap(B^-1,-C,zeros(10,10)) in matlab?

Comment: Suppose you have a solution `M`, then you can always scale both sides and the range is respected hence that constraint is a redundant one or your current formulation is not what you mean. Moreover, you can formulate your question as `[I B]*blkdiag(M,-M)*[I;C] = 0` as a kernel representation.

Comment: @percusse thank you that worked flawlessly and i also got a similar answer when i posted it to math.stackexchange.com ...really got through hell for me ..now i can focus on the pure programming part of it .. thank you